# SweetAlert2 disallow outside click after confirm

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to create an alert similar to the [ajax-example](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request), but allowing outside click dismiss **before** confirming. After the user clicks confirm I would like to disallow outside click until the operation is finished.

Setting the config variable `allowOutsideClick` to false like in the example will never allow outside click and I don't see a valid method in the docs to achieve this behavior programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to pass the function to the `allowOutsideClick` parameter:

```
allowOutsideClick: () => { 
  // add your logic here and return boolean 
}
```

Your case:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Submit email to run ajax request',
  input: 'email',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (email) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
      }, 3000)
    })
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```